# How to get the current url with query string in Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel 8 with Livewire. I have created a search component with a lot of options, which are added to the query string.

Now I have the problem, that when I open the detail page of a result with `<a href=`, the query string is not saved anywhere and i cannot go back to the latest query.

Before I changed everything to Livewire, I've saved `url()->current()` to a session variable and opened that when going back. The problem with livewire is, even if the url shown is my current page with actual query params, current url returns `livewire/message/nameofcomponent`.

I have no idea how to go back from the detail page and get the latest query combinations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to is to simply use `history.back()`:

`<a href="javascript:window.history.back()">...</a>`

This should re-open the previous page including all query parameters.

Alternatively, you can pass query parameters to the detail page as well and rebuild the route. But this comes with significant more work.

Comment: The JS version works, but I have chosen to regenerate the query string during the updated() method and save it to the session(). works like charm ;-)

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea and saves you from passing it around. But it would cause trouble if someone works in multiple tabs (like I do constantly), wouldn't it?

Comment: right, that can mix up things... damn... I think I have to find another solution ;-(

Comment: The `history.back()` approach should work for multiple tabs as the information is kept within the browser

Comment: @SaschaKlein what method did you come up with?

Comment: @alex Sorry for the late reply - haven't received the notification. I have now created a middleware which saves the current url to a session variable. This way I have excluded the detail page and I can get the latest from the session variable.